# How to optimize this for loop for bigger data in r?

Tags: r, optimization

I have some reproducible data, (my original dataset contains about 2,000,000 rows). For this reason, my for loop becomes inefficient and will take a long time to run this much data. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to run this data. I attached my code with reproducible data

```
#----Reproducible data example--------------------#
#Upload first data set#
words1<-c("How","did","Quebec","nationalists","see","their","province","as","a","nation","in","the","1960s")
words2<-c("Why","does","volicty","effect","time",'?',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
words3<-c("How","do","I","wash","a","car",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
library<-c("The","the","How","see","as","a","for","then","than","example")
embedding1<-c(.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,.3,.46,.48,.53,.42)
embedding2<-c(.1,.5,.4,.8,.9,.3,.98,.73,.48,.56)
df <- data.frame(words1,words2,words3)
names(df)<-c("words1","words2","words3")

#--------Upload 2nd dataset-------#
df2 <- data.frame(library,embedding1, embedding2)
names(df2)<-c("library","embedding1","embedding2")
df2$meanembedding=rowMeans(df2[c("embedding1","embedding2")],na.rm=T)
df2<-df2[,-c(2,3)]

#-----Find columns--------#
l=ncol(df)
names<-names(df)
head(names)
classes<-sapply(df[,c(1:l)],class)
head(classes)

#------Combine and match libary to training data------#
require(gridExtra)
List = list()
for( name in names){
  df1<-df[,name]
  df1<-as.data.frame(df1)
  x_train2<-merge(x= df1, y = df2, 
                  by.x = "df1", by.y = 'library',all.x=T, sort=F)
  x_train2<-x_train2[,-1]
  x_train2<-as.data.frame(x_train2)
  names(x_train2) <- name
  List[[length(List)+1]] = x_train2
}
```

Comment: your code produces an error: `Error in data.frame(words1, words2, words3) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 13, 6`

Comment: I fixed this problem with NA values, thanks

Comment: For starters, **never** use base functions as object names! `names()` is a base function, so the line `names<-names(df)` is bad practice. At least use something like `temp_names`, `mynames` or the likes. Same with `name` as the looping index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use `lapply`:

```
myList2 <- lapply(names(df), function(x){
  y <- merge(x = df[, x, drop = FALSE], 
        y = df2,
        by.x = x,
        by.y = 'library',
        all.x = T, 
        sort = F)[, -1, drop = FALSE]
  names(y) <- x
  return(y)
})
```

We loop over the vector `names(df)`, subset and merge on the fly, using `[drop = FALSE]` to prevent the simplification from a one-column-data.frame to a vector, and overwrite the column name. The output is a list.

Post script: You technically do not need the `drop = FALSE` if you use `df[x]` instead of `df[, x]`, as @RuiBarradas pointed out. But I think it is helpful to know about the `drop = FALSE` option in cases where you need to subset both rows and columns.

Comment: If `df` is a dataframe, so is `df[i]`, no need for two instructions one of which a call to `as.data.frame`. And the same for `x_train2<-x_train2[,-1]` versus `x_train2<-x_train2[-1]`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on simplifying the whole loop, there's a lot to be optimized.

Comment: Worked out a solution with `lapply`. This should simplify and speed up things quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

when joining on large data volumes, give data.table a try...

```
library( data.table )

dt <- as.data.table( df )
dt2 <- as.data.table ( df2 )

lapply( names(dt), function(x) {
  on_expr <- parse( text = paste0( "c( library = \"", x, "\")" ) )
  dt2[dt, on = eval( on_expr )][,2]
})

# [[1]]
#     meanembedding
#  1:          0.55
#  2:            NA
#  3:            NA
#  4:            NA
#  5:          0.80
#  6:            NA
#  7:            NA
#  8:          0.90
#  9:          0.30
# 10:            NA
# 11:            NA
# 12:          0.55
# 13:            NA
# 
# [[2]]
#     meanembedding
#  1:            NA
#  2:            NA
#  3:            NA
#  4:            NA
#  5:            NA
#  6:            NA
#  7:            NA
#  8:            NA
#  9:            NA
# 10:            NA
# 11:            NA
# 12:            NA
# 13:            NA
# 
# [[3]]
#     meanembedding
#  1:          0.55
#  2:            NA
#  3:            NA
#  4:            NA
#  5:          0.30
#  6:            NA
#  7:            NA
#  8:            NA
#  9:            NA
# 10:            NA
# 11:            NA
# 12:            NA
# 13:            NA
```